# How to bind values to object that is return from Store Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using SPs for select/insert operations on Entity Framework. To do that I am using function importion feature of EF to define my SPs in EF. But I am locked on return types of SPs.

I want to bind the values that is return by SPs to entities with navigation properties, but couldn't find how to do that.

My Datebase is:

```
Questions:
-Id,
-QuestionText

Choices:
-Id,
-QuestionId,
-Text
```

My SP is:

```
SELECT 
q.Id,
q.QuestionText,
c.Id as ChoiceId,
c.[Text] as ChoiceText,
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Poll.Question q1 
WHERE q1.Id > @p_LastQuestionId
ORDER BY q1.Id DESC 
) q
LEFT JOIN Choice c ON q.Id = c.QuestionId
```

What I am getting now is:

```
Question
-Id
-QuestionText
-ChoiceId
-ChoiceText
```

What I want to see my function import return type is a Question Entity with a collection property which has the related choices:

```
Question
-Id (Int)
-QuestionText (String)
-List<Choices> Choices (Choice)

Choice
-Id (Int)
-Text (String)
```

Comment: But how would EF know how to split the SP result into multiple entities? It just sees a result set of four columns. EF does not inspect the SP code to see the origin of the values.

Comment: Hi Gert, yea I have the same opinion with you ,I know that there must be a configuration for column mapping to entities, is there a configuration for that? Entity framework use a mapping byself when using linq queries. Do we use that or configure a new one? I heard a library called EFExtensions and its doing what I need, but I want to  know that there is a solution for this situation or not before using this extension.

Comment: The question is, why do you use an SP for a read operation? Usually read operations are done through DbSets in the context, while CUD operations can be mapped to SPs. Of course you can delegate "expensive" read operations spanning multiple entities to SPs, but then you have to deal with the flattened results yourself. I can't imagine that any library will be able to do this for you. EFExtensions was last modified in 2010: dead end.